# How to retrieve Django model id from admin page via javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-admin

Suppose I have a Django model like this one.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

I registered it in admin via

```
admin.site.register(Car)
```

I want to add custom JS button for admin site object view, which will alert value of a color of an instance of a Car model. So when I press it I get something like "The car with id **13** is **red**"

How can I get id of an object and value of a color field via JavaScript?

Comment: You can save  click on button check if this is good `def __str__(self): return f"The car with id {self.id} is {self.color}"`

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. It's just an example and in reality a have a lot of fields like `color` with a very long value in it.

Comment: You want this button side of the list of Car models?

Comment: No not in list, but in object view, near `color` field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to extend `change_form.html` template for you app (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)

For example I have `store` app and inside `models.py` I've put `Car` model.

Then inside `store/templates/admin/store/change_form.html` I've put this template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block content %}
{{ block.super }}
        <script>
                const object = {
                        pk: {{ original.pk }},
                        color: '{{ original.color }}',
                };
        </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
{{ block.super }}

<li>
        <a href="" id="my-button">My button</a>
        <script>
                const button = document.getElementById('my-button');
                button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        alert(`The car with ${object.pk} is ${object.color}`); 
                });
        </script>
</li>

{% endblock %}
```

Admin view:

[image]

Comment: Aha, so it's available via {{ original }} in template. Great, thank you!